# How to create a Play project with a specific version?

Tags: scala, playframework

How can I create a new play project for a specific version?

using `sbt new playframework/play-scala-seed.g8` it will always create a project pointing to the last version of Play (in this case 2.7).
The thing is that there isn't support for that version in gradle yet and I don't want to use sbt.

How can I specify version 2.6.6?

Comment: Just a guess... look at `project/plugins.sbt` and you may see a line like `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.7.0")`. Adjust the version there and rebuild

Comment: what about changing the `def playVersion = "2.7.0"` version string in build.gradle? Never used gradle before. but in sbt it is also just changing the version string for the play plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your /project/plugins.sbt file you can specify which version of play you want to use.

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.6")
```

Reference : https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/BuildOverview#Play-plugin-for-sbt-(/project/plugins.sbt)